# Why time complexicity of this code is O(n) instead of O(log n)

Tags: loops, time-complexity, big-o

Following code's time complexity is O(n log n)
I think for the outer loop log n
but for the inner loop n.
So, O(n logn )

```
x = n 
while ( x > 0 ) { 
    y = n 
    while ( y > 0 ) { 
        y = y - 1 
    } 
    x = x / 2 
}
```

But following code's time complexity is O(n)

```
x = n 
while ( x > 0 ) { 
    y = x 
    while ( y > 0 ) { 
        y = y - 1 
    } 
    x = x / 2 
}
```

Why is above code's time complexity is O(n)?

Comment: I'm confused about the language tag you have added. Your post doesn't look like `python` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the number of iterations of the inner loop is reduced by the same ratio as `x` is reduced. The total number of iterations will always be approximately `2n - 1` (it's exact when `n` is a power of 2, it deviates a bit for other numbers). Big-O ignores coefficients and lower-order components to the sum, so that's O(n).

For instance, when `n == 16`, the first iteration of the outer loop performs 16 iterations of the inner loop. The second iteration performs 8, then 4, and so on. So the total number is `16+8+4+2+1 == 31`.